# Which is source IP and destination IP for this Cisco ASA Firewall Log?

Tags: nat, firewall, syslog

Built inbound ICMP connection for faddr 10.1.6.3/1 gaddr 10.24.5.2/0 laddr 10.4.1.2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A five second google search told me that:

faddr = foreign address

gaddr = global address (after NAT)

laddr = local address (pre NAT)

Since this is an inbound connection, the source IP address is the foreign one : `10.1.6.3`
The original destination address is `10.24.5.2` which has been translated to the final destination address `10.4.1.2`